# Puppeteer returning undefined when defined as variable

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

so this is a weird thing.

I am running a puppeteer test and everything works when I console.log the count.

```
 console.log((await page.$$('.list-view > ul > .selected > h5 > .msg-title')).length);
```

However, when I try to wrap the count in a variable or const, it returns undefined.

```
let test = await page.$$('.list-view > ul > .selected > h5 > .msg-title').length
console.log(test)
```

results:

```
undefined.
```

id like to eventually write this in a json format to save it to a DB.

Comment: It's becouse it's an await function... It console.logs() before the result comes back from the db.

Comment: `let test = await page.$$('.list-view > ul > .selected > h5 > .msg-title').length` -> `let test = (await page.$$('.list-view > ul > .selected > h5 > .msg-title')).length` otherwise you try to essentially `await promise.length`

Comment: It's a precedence issue. You need to put `()` around `await page.$$(...)` prior to `.length`. Otherwise you're doing `page.$$(...).length` and then `await`ing that. Promises don't have a `length` property. :-) (And no, this wasn't obvious. It bites everyone at one time or another.)

Comment: @BudaÖrs - No, that's not the reason (although it's true that nothing waits for the promise to settle). (Also, `await` isn't a function. :-) )

Comment: Yeah, you are right:) I didn't say tho that `await` is a function :-)